# Term parent in node.tpl.php

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms, nodes, theming

I have an Entity taxonomy Reference field in my content type.

I need to print parent of the term linked to my node in node.tpl.php (link to that term). How can I do it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. This is my code:

```
<?php
    $term = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_taxonomy_term');
    $parent = current(taxonomy_get_parents($field[0]['target_id']));
    print l($parent->name, 'taxonomy/term/'. $parent->tid);
?>
```